# Truncado JS no toma 0 a la derecha

Tags: javascript, jquery

como puedo truncar un numero decimal con ceros a la derecha, ya que siempre trunca hasta el numero natural, es decir si hay un 0 no lo toma

```js
function myRound(num, dec) {
  var exp = Math.pow(10, dec || 2); // 2 decimales por defecto
  return parseInt(num * exp, 10) / exp;
}

var num = 2.70;
console.log('Con 1 decimales:', myRound(num, 1));
console.log('Con 2 decimales:', myRound(num));
console.log('Con 3 decimales:', myRound(num, 3));
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si quieres añadir ceros a la derecha, es un tema de formato: tienes que usar strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres ceros extras a la derecha, no puedes forzar a JS a mostrar el float `2.7` como `2.70` a menos que lo castees como String. Para eso, el primitivo `Number` ofrece el método `toFixed` (que devuelve strings).

```js
function myRound(num, dec) {
  if(dec===undefined) {
     dec=2;  // 2 decimales por defecto
  }
  var exp = Math.pow(10, dec);
  return Number(parseInt(num * exp, 10) / exp).toFixed(dec);
}

var num = 2.70;
console.log('Con 1 decimales:', myRound(num, 1));
console.log('Con 2 decimales:', myRound(num));
console.log('Con 3 decimales:', myRound(num, 3));
```